# jQuery .change() only fires on the first change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
$.each (t.config.industry, function (i, v) {
    $(v).change(function () {
        console.log("Industry change!");
    });
});
```

`t.config.industry` is an array of `<select>` ids. `t.config.industry: ["#W2549_Sl", "#W2601_Sl", "#W2654_Sl"]` I have several `<select>` boxes on the page and I'm tracking them all. Any time any of them change I want to fire something.

Obviously I'm trying to do more than simply console.log, but for the sake of this post I'll limit it to that. On my website the console.log only prints *once*, on the first change. On subsequent changes of the `<select>` dropdown menu it does not fire.

Anyone seen this before?

NOTE: I cannot change the HTML mark-up at all.

Comment: It is a little hard to decipher without seeing some markup, but you are containing the change in an each function. Each applies the function once for each element in the batch typically, I have never nestled a change function within an each.

Comment: The mark up is just a bunch of select boxes. But I can't change the mark-up. It's hard to explain, but I'm stuck with the mark-up.

Answer (score 4):

I've witnessed this behavior when the ids of the multiple select elements weren't unique.  To resolve the issue in my case, I simply removed the ids, defined a class, and modified the jQuery selector to use the specified class.  For example:

```
    <select class="some_value" some_id="<%= some[:id] %>">

    $(".some_value").change(function() {
        var some_id = $(this).attr("some_id");
        alert('some_id: ' + some_id);
    });
```

Frankly I consider the behavior a bug in jQuery.  Why should it work successfully once and fail thereafter?

Answer (score 1):

If you could add a common class to each of the select elements you want to monitor, that would simplify your code immensely. Try this (jQuery 1.7 required for the `on` method):

```
$(document).on('change','select.monitorme', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id')+' changed!');
});

$.each (t.config.industry, function (i, v) {
    $(v).change(function () {
        $(this).addClass('monitorme'); // or just add the class to your markup
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `#` before the `v` (your `id`) for this selector to work

```
$.each(t.config.industry, function (i, v) {
   $("#" + v).change(function () {
      console.log("Industry change!");
   });
});
```

Comment: t.config.industry is an array of all my select boxes' IDs.

Comment: @JesseAtkinson updated, try that :-) if that doesnt work then please post the actual contents of your array in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try rewrite it in a such way  HTML

```
        <select id="main_industry">
          <?foreach ($industry as $item ){?>
          <option value="<?=$item['id']?>"><?=$item['title']?></option>
          <?}?>
        </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   $('#main_industry').change(function() {
      // your stuff here
      console.log ($(this).val());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net, it's working in my project correctly.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtvisitname" AutoPostBack="true" class="txtno" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
    runat="server" onchange="return selectChange()">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--SELECT--" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT1" Value="VISIT1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT2" Value="VISIT2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT3" Value="VISIT3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT4" Value="VISIT4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="VISIT5" Value="VISIT5" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Unscheduled  VISIT" Value="Unscheduled  VISIT" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Function:

```
selectChange() {
    if ($("[id*=txtvisitname]").val() == "Unscheduled  VISIT") {
        $(".other").show();
    } else {
        $(".other").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You're setting your listener on every option it seems. Put it on your select only !