# jQuery 'change' doesn't show most up-to-date data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a jQuery `change` function that populates a dropdown list of `Titles` from the user selection of a `Site` dropdown list

```
$("#SiteID").on("change", function() {
  var titleUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Form/GetTitles";
  var ddlsource = "#SiteID";

  $.getJSON(titleUrl, { SiteID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function(data) {
    var items = "";
    $("#TitleID").empty();

    $.each(data, function(i, title) {
      items +=
        "<option value='" + title.value + "'>" + title.text + "</option>";
    });

    $("#TitleID").html(items);
  });
});
```

The controller returns JSON object that populates another dropdown list.

```
public JsonResult GetTitles(int siteId)
        {
            IEnumerable<Title> titleList; 

            titleList = repository.Titles
                .Where(o => o.SiteID == siteId)
                .OrderBy(o => o.Name);

            return Json(new SelectList(titleList, "TitleID", "Name"));
        }
```

The markup is:

```
<select id="SiteID" asp-for="SiteID" asp-items="@Model.SiteList" value="@Model.Site.SiteID" class="form-control"></select>

<select id="TitleID"></select>
```

The problem is that the controller method is only touched on the FIRST time a selection is made. For example,

1. The first time SITE 1 is selected, the controller method will return the updated list of Titles corresponding to SITE 1
2. If SITE 2 is selected from the dropdown, the controller will return the updated list of Titles corresponding to SITE 2
3. The user adds/deletes Titles in the database corresponding to SITE 1
4. User returns to the form and selects SITE 1 from the dropdown. The list still shows the results from step 1 above, not the updates from step 3

If I stop debugging and restart, the selection will now show the updates from step 3.

Similar behavior described in [jQuery .change() only fires on the first change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772985/jquery-change-only-fires-on-the-first-change) but I'm hoping for a better solution than to stop using jQuery id's

The JSON response is:

```
[{"disabled":false,"group":null,"selected":false,"text":"Title2","value":"2"},{"disabled":false,"group":null,"selected":false,"text":"Title3","value":"1002"},{"disabled":false,"group":null,"selected":false,"text":"Title4","value":"2004"},{"disabled":false,"group":null,"selected":false,"text":"Title5","value":"3"},{"disabled":false,"group":null,"selected":false,"text":"Title6","value":"9004"}]
```

Comment: Could you please add html and json response on change event to drop down ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to review the json response...if you could point me to how to do so, I'll provide it. I've added the controller method if that helps. It does provide the right functionality on the first change event

Comment: Wait... are you saying the change event IS firing, it's just not giving you new information? It should be pretty easy to figure out whether or not a change event is happening... your option 3 seems to indicate that it is happening, which conflicts with the title of your question.

Comment: could you please put your JSON response text in your question?

Comment: @KevinB it seems to fire the first time a particular item in the `SelectList` is chosen, but does not fire again if that same item is selected on subsequent changes

Comment: Add a console.log to the change event. Prove that it isn't firing. You may instead have a caching problem.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra I edited the question to show the JSON response

Comment: @KevinB When I examine the network communication, it does call the method, but receives a response from the cache. Is there a way to prevent the response from coming from the cache and instead get it from the controller (in case changes have been made since the last time it was cached)?

Comment: The server can return headers that prevent caching, or you can use jquery's cache option to prevent it (that would require switching to $.ajax).

Comment: @KevinB I'll look elsewhere, but could you provide examples of what you're suggesting? I have a feeling that's the answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the JSON result was being read from cache as @KevinB pointed out. This was fixed by adding the following line within the change function

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```